# Set Radio button value in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have aura:iteration and group of radio buttons for each line:

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.customList }" var="customListItem">
   <ui:inputRadio name="{! customListItem.Id }" label="Status 1" click="{! c.addToMap }"/>
   <ui:inputRadio name="{! customListItem.Id }" label="Status 2" click="{! c.addToMap }"/>
   <ui:inputRadio name="{! customListItem.Id }" label="Status 3" click="{! c.addToMap }"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

I want to set default value to radio button based on status from customListItem.

Comment: Answer to my similar question should help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158792/unable-to-set-lightningselect-value-when-using-dynamically-created-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value of ui:inputSelect.

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.customList }" var="customListItem">
   <ui:inputRadio value="{!if(customListItem.VALUE == 'YOUR VALUE', true, false)}" name="{! customListItem.Id }" label="Status 1" click="{! c.addToMap }"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot! I tried IF(), but it doesn't work :(