# how does get opportunity records list into picklist dynamically using lightning components in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
public with sharing class OpportunitiesController1 {
 @AuraEnabled
   public static list<opportunity> getProductByName() {
        list<opportunity> options= [select id, name from opportunity ];
        return options;
    }
}
```

component:

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunitiesController1" implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">


    <div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
        <lightning:card >
            <aura:set attribute="title">

                <p class="slds-text-heading--label">
            <lightning:icon iconName="action:add_contact" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
           Hello! User Name
        </p>
            </aura:set>
            <div  class="slds-container--small slds-container--center" > <lightning:buttonGroup>
        <lightning:button label="Refresh"/>
        <lightning:button label="Edit"/>
        <lightning:button label="Save"/>
    </lightning:buttonGroup>
               </div>
             <div  class="slds-container--small slds-container--Right"> Close Window:<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" alternativeText="Close window." />
         <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Download" iconName="utility:download" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
            </div>
        </lightning:card>

    <div class="slds-grid">
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>



   <div class="slds-page-header">
    <div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
        <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Basic  Information</p>
    <div class="slds-grid">
    </div></div></div></div> 
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadOptions}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="options" type="opportunity[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="options1" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" default="Select a Color"/>

    <aura:attribute name="Result" type="Integer" />


    <div class="c-container">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="space">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                <div class="slds-container--small slds-container--left">
                    <div class="slds-container--small slds-container--left">
                    <lightning:select name="mySelect" label="colors:" aura:id="mySelect1" value="{!v.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.onchange}" >
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                            <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.name}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                         </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>
 </div>
             </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                2
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                3
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            4
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
 </aura:component>
```

Component controller:

```
({
 loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
     helper.getProductByName(component);
})
```

Component Helper

```
getProductByName: function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts=new Array(); 
        var action = component.get("c.getProductByName");
        //var rec = component.get("v.mySelect");
         $A.getCallback(function(callback) {
             //var action = component.get("c.getProductByName");
             var rec = component.get("v.mySelect");
             action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++)
                {
                    opts.push({"class": "OpportunitiesController", label:a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
                } 
                 component.find("mySelect1").set("v.options", opts);

                 rec.set("v.mySelect", opts);
                 console.log('test picklist value'+opts);
             });
             $A.enqueueAction(action);
         });
    },
```

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Aside from formatting issues, pleas take some time to use words to describe what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck. Currently your post is just a code dump.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lightning:select - Set default value based on sObject List from apex controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154899/lightningselect-set-default-value-based-on-sobject-list-from-apex-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some bugs in your component helper method rest code is fine, try the fixed code:

```
getProductByName: function(c){
    var options = []; 
    var action = c.get("c.getProductByName");        
    action.setCallback(this, function(r){
        var data = r.getReturnValue();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            options.push({selected: false, label: data[i].Name, value: data[i].Id});
        } 
        c.set("v.options", options);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Small change in Component controller:

```
({
    loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.getProductByName(component);
    }/* You missed the closing bracker */
})
```

**UPDATE**
Bugs:

```
/* no need of */
$A.getCallback(function(callback){

/* This statement is unnecessary, You are not using this value anywhere. */
/* component.get("v.mySelect"); this statement returns the value of mySelect attribute not the reference to the attribute. */
var rec = component.get("v.mySelect");

/* Select element doesn't have any options property. */
component.find("mySelect1").set("v.options", opts);

/* To set the attribute value the syntax is: component.set("v.mySelect", opts) not you are using */
rec.set("v.mySelect", opts);
```

Comment: would you mind pointing out the bugs and explain why your code should work? [answer] This will help educate users and help them better understand in the future.

Comment: I got  the following error message when i run application.

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error in $A.getCallback() [options is not defined]
Callback failed: apex://OpportunitiesController1/ACTION$getProductByName
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:Productcmp}

Comment: But in the updated code there is no `$A.getCallback()` a method used by me.

Comment: Hi,I got it with out error.
thanks